# Bugged Mobile App To Test

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, functional, application-software-testing, mobile-applications

I am looking for some bugged apps in order to perform functional test training and/or test some techniques.

I found some resources like [this](https://github.com/payatu/diva-android), or a list of web application like [it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Vulnerable_Web_Applications_Directory_Project#tab=Off-Line_apps). However these are examples of vulnerable apps from a security perspective.

Instead, I need some mobile apps having functional bugs. Are there some resources in this perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just take any low-rated application from any application store and it will be highly-likely a "bugged mobile app".

Another option is to install early-access application. Here is the example for Google Play Market:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In https://m.apkpure.com/br/apkpure/com.apkpure.aegon you can get several apps APKs to install and test

e.g.

- Online Shop Demo
- Demo Shop
- RP Shop Online DEMO
- My Demo App
- Demo app